# javascript - should my code leak memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, jwplayer

If I call this function many times, should it leak memory?

One thing made me suspitious: here I assign to instance player. The player has listeners - onPlay and others. So when I run function playJW, it does everything. And so those listeners work **after** the function execution finished. I know that they work after function execution, because video file runs much more time than function takes to execute.

So if I call this function many times - there are made many copies of those listeners or how it is working?

```
this.playJW = function(vid) {

    $('#jwplayer').show();

    // this was file name with .avi , we need only beggining
    vid = vid.split('.');

    var folder = /dogs6_4mb/;       
    if(this._isMobile()) {          
        folder = '/dogs6_2mb/';
    }

    var player = jwplayer('jwplayer').setup({
        file: video_files_url + folder + vid[0] + '.mp4',
        height: '100%',     
        width: '100%',
        controls: true,
        autostart: true    
    });

    this.isPlaying = false;

    player.onPlay(function() {
        player.setControls(false);
        // to make not pause on display click
        self.isPlaying = true;          
    });

    player.onDisplayClick(function() {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            player.play();              
            self.isPlaying = true;              
        }
    });

    player.onComplete(function() {
        $('#jwplayer').hide();
    });     
};
```

I tried checking memory usage with developer tools - first time it looked that it is increasing a bit, until 11 MB, then I refreshed page and also disabled chrome plugins. Now web page does not run over 12.4 MB. But test did not take long time.

I want to understand are those listeners cleaned somehow and how browser knows that they are not used anymore?

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/e9dRt/3/

Comment: Do you have an example of this running for debugging?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am not sure, but jwplayer test version might have limit of how much plays it makes. But if really needed, maybe later I could make on jsfiddle.

Comment: There is no test version of the JW Player that has a limit on plays. If you could put up a jsfiddle, that would be great.

Comment: yea, my mistake, noticed that there is 500 limit of hosted files plays in hte jwplayer site as I understand. ALso made jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true, our free hosting as that limit.